# Keyboard shortcut to go to previous window

Tags: macos, window-manager

I use two monitors.

**On monitor A I have:**

- Chrome window

**On monitor B I have:**

- Chrome window
- Text editor window

Let's say I view the Chrome window on monitor A, and then Text editor window on monitor B. If I want to go back to the Chrome window on monitor A, how do I do that?

Right now I do it by Cmd+Tab and then Cmd+`, but this is too many keypresses.

Comment: Unless you're willing to launch two instances of chrome, no there is not. And that is not too many keypresses. It's does not even qualify as many in English, it's couple where you only have to lift one finger since you can hold down command. You could invest in a tool like Keyboard Maestro and write a script if you really think that is less work than two keypresses. That script will be at least 1000+ keypresses.

Comment: It may not seem like a big deal to you, but I switch between windows hundreds of times a day and am continuously slightly frustrated when Cmd+tab goes to a different window than I expect. I'm not sure I would go so far as to write a script myself at this point, but if there is a solution someone else has already created, I'll gladly use it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this free software that is capable of doing what I want: https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch